# Full page numbers in biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex-sbl` and this style abbreviated page numbers of (journal) articles (e.g. "159-74" instead of "159-174"). How can I circumvent this?
in German-speaking bibliographies, it is not common to give abbreviated page numbers. Thus, I want create such result:

> Leyerle, Blake. “John Chrysostom on the Gaze.” JECS 1 (1993): 159–174.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{leyerle:1993,
author = {Leyerle, Blake},
title = {John Chrysostom on the Gaze},
shorttitle = {Chrysostom},
journaltitle = {Journal of Early Christian Studies},
shortjournal = {JECS},
volume = {1},
date = {1993},
pages = {159-174}
}


@incollection{Ab.2005,
 author = {Ab, Tom},
 date = {2005},
 title = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 shorttitle = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 editor = {Zenk, Raul},
 pages = {132--144},
 location = {Rom},
 booktitle = {Studi},
series = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
 shortseries = {OCA},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{leyerle:1993}.} oder\footcite{Ab.2005}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagepages}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagesin}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1} \usebibmacro{in}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}` (untested because I don't have the time right now). If you get an error because `\mknormrange` is undefined, your `biblatex` is outdated. (In which case you can replace all `\mknormrange{#1}`s with just `#1` or add `\providecommand*{\mknormrange}[1]{#1}` to the preamble).

Comment: Perfect, it works; Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-sbl` uses `\mkcomprange` to compress numeric ranges in a number of fields. You'll want to replace all occurrences of `\mkcomprange` with `\mknormrange`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagepages}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagesin}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1} \usebibmacro{in}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{altpostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagepages}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagesin}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1} \usebibmacro{in}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{altpostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}


\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{leyerle:1993,
  author       = {Leyerle, Blake},
  title        = {John Chrysostom on the Gaze},
  shorttitle   = {Chrysostom},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Early Christian Studies},
  shortjournal = {JECS},
  volume       = {1},
  date         = {1993},
  pages        = {159-174}
}
@incollection{Ab.2005,
  author      = {Ab, Tom},
  date        = {2005},
  title       = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
  editor      = {Zenk, Raul},
  pages       = {132--144},
  location    = {Rom},
  booktitle   = {Studi},
  series      = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
  shortseries = {OCA},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\autocite[Vgl.:][]{leyerle:1993} oder\footcite{Ab.2005}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ab, Tom. ‘Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora’. Pages 132–144 in Studi. Edited by Raul Zenk. OCA. Rom, 2005.//Leyerle, Blake. ‘John Chrysostom on the Gaze’. JECS 1 (1993): 159–174.]

If you are using an outdated version of `biblatex` `\mknormrange` might not be available, in that case replace `\mknormrange{#1}` with `#1` and `\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1}` with `\mkpageprefix{#1}`.